# Launching Play Store when connecting USB (or BLE) device

Tags: android, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-play

Does anyone know if it is possible to automatically open Play Store when a device is connected via USB (or BLE) on an Android phone or tablet for the first time ?
The purpose is to make sure that users install a bundled app when connecting a new device (eg a MIDI keyboard or whatever) for the first time. It would obviously have to be part of Android OS (which version ?)

Thanks

Comment: @raj prove it (your answer does not address my question).

Answer (score 0):

first copy bradcastrecieverclass from below

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;

public class Usbinserted extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

             i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

             ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                "com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp",
                "com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.AssetBrowserActivity");

            i.setComponent(cn);

            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            ctx.startActivity(i);

 //  Log.d(TAG,"USB connected..");


}

}
```

now copy and paste it in your manifest file

```
 <receiver android:name=".Usbinserted" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" /> <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and add these permissions to manifest file

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
```

Comment: You did not answer my question. There is NO application initially installed. The problem is to automatically trigger a connection to the Play Store to download my app.

Comment: for that you need to install an application contains broadcast reciever